# Error calling external DLL

Tags: c#, .net, c, dllimport, extern

My .NET code calls a function from an external DLL:

```
[DllImport("MyExternal.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            private static extern int loadMyExternalFunction();

loadMyExternalFunction();
```

The error is:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

What is the cause of this error and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Not enough informations. It could be a wrong calling convention or an error inside the `loadMyExternalFunction` function call.

Comment: What more information can I give?  It is definitely not a problem with the `loadMyExternalFunction` because it is a proprietary DLL that is used widely without problem.

Comment: If that code is all you have and: 1) calling convention is right. 2) function prototype is right. 3) called function does not need any extra initialization code. 4) called function works well with .NET (yes, it's not an assumption for every compiler/in every condition). Then the problem is inside the called function.

Comment: It's definitely not a problem inside the function, because it only happens on one machine, but I want to know what the problem is.

Comment: Is it a 32 bit DLL and you're running inside a 64 bit process (or Any CPU) on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: All this is happening on XP 32-bit.

Comment: The issue you are getting is infamous "GPF" (general protection fault) error and there are probably at millions of defferent causes for it. Based on amount of information you are willing to provide your steps are: create small sample that reproduces the problem and contact whoever created that "proprietary DLL" asking them to fix it.

Comment: Then I really think the problem is inside the called function. If, **just calling it**, you get that error then the problem is there. The fact that it works on 1000+ machines doesn't mean it works always. Did you check with a debugger what happens there?!

Comment: It just breaks with that exception on the function call. It does not debug the DLL.

Comment: @PaulLassiter: please, post native function prototype.

Comment: @Dennis: how do I get that? All I have is the above and the DLL.

Comment: @PaulLassiter: this information usually comes from DLL vendor. You've got somewhere C# import declaration...

Comment: @Dennis: do you mean `private static extern int loadMyExternalFunction(); ` ?

Comment: @PaulLassiter: yes, I do. Vendor must provide C++ headers for the functions being imported.